# Binutils documentation compilation problem

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make, latex, info

I'm trying to compile and install binutils+GCC for my machine on my own. I have compiled lastest binutils sources without getting any error, but installation seems to have some problems with `gas` documentation.

Here is my installation log:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/src/binutils-2.23.51-1/build/etc'
make[2]: Entering directory '/src/binutils-2.23.51-1/build/gas'
Making install in doc
make[3]: Entering directory '/src/binutils-2.23.51-1/build/gas/doc'
make[4]: Entering directory '/src/binutils-2.23.51-1/build/gas/doc'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
../../../gas/doc/c-arc.texi:223: command @bullet not accepting argument in brace should not be on @table line
../../../gas/doc/c-arm.texi:393: command @bullet not accepting argument in brace should not be on @table line
../../../gas/doc/c-arm.texi:394: warning: @item missing argument
...
../../../gas/doc/c-cr16.texi:65: warning: @item missing argument
../../../gas/doc/c-tic54x.texi:113: @code expected brace
...
../../../gas/doc/c-i386.texi:979: warning: node prev `i386-Bugs' in menu `i386-Arch' and in sectioning `i386-16bit' differ
...
../../../gas/doc/c-xtensa.texi:9: warning: node `Z80-Dependent' is next for `Xtensa-Dependent' in menu but not in sectioning
Makefile:397: recipe for target 'as.info' failed
make[4]: *** [as.info] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/src/binutils-2.23.51-1/build/gas/doc'
Makefile:592: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/src/binutils-2.23.51-1/build/gas/doc'
Makefile:2182: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/src/binutils-2.23.51-1/build/gas'
Makefile:4761: recipe for target 'install-gas' failed
make[1]: *** [install-gas] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/src/binutils-2.23.51-1/build'
Makefile:2141: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

The output is very large and some of the warnings are repeating (they just occur on different lines). It looks like the problem is caused by `as.info` file, and I guess I'm using old version of some tool for `.texi` files. I don't know what to do now. Does anybody have any idea what can I do for running the installation successfully?